# How to use different alt for different images in srcset?

Tags: html, responsive

I have two image tags as follows

```
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1">
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2">
```

And now I setup these two images as responsive by `srcset` attribute as follows

```
<img src="image1.jpg"
     srcset="image1.jpg 150w,
             image2.jpg 300w"
     sizes ="(max-width:991px) 287px,
             (max-width:479px) 125px
             290px"
     alt="">
```

Now I struggle with adding above two alts into the single alt in the responsive img tag. I tried `alt="image1, image2"` but didn't work. Is any way to do this?

Comment: The images are meant to represent the same thing. You shouldn't be presenting users different content just because their screen happens to be a different size.

Comment: In order to increase site performances, all Google speed test, pingdom, GTmetrix and other site performance testing tools are suggesting to use different sized images for different devices rather using the same image. If I can provide a small image for small devices, why shouldn't I do it?

Comment: In reply to your comment @DeanJohns. You should absolutely provide the user with different versions (resolutions) of the same image. This is what google is encouraging but being that it is the same image, the default alt tag should be the same. You shouldn't supply two different images under the same picture element. Do you understand?

Comment: @DeanJohns, you've misunderstood me. You _are_ supposed to provide multiple renderings of the _same image_ that has the _same meaning_ which is the _same content_. You **are not** supposed to provide **different images** that have **different meaning** which would be **different content**.

Comment: @zzzzBov , rodchunha yes now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the picture element. You can't use different alt descriptions for your picture as the source element doesn't take an alt attribute. It can however take a `title` attribute.

See the example below from w3schools where they give a generic alt tag to the picture element default `img` element.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

This article outlining a custom polyfill to accomplish what you want might be helpful too: https://iandevlin.com/blog/2014/12/html5/defining-multiple-captions-and-alt-text-for-responsive-images/